# How to catch a signal emitted by bundled GDB in clion upon pressing "stop" button?

Tags: c++, gdb, clion

While debugging in clion, there is a "stop" button (red square) that stops a running program. Currently, I am writing tests and trying to debug them. My test cases create temporary directories and files that should be cleaned up afterwards, but neither the destructors nor the signal handlers are called upon pressing the button.

This is how I handle the signals (many of them, since I'm not sure which is actually used by GDB):

```
DLOG_S(INFO) << "Registering signal handlers for test files cleanup";
if (signal(SIGABRT, TemporaryDirectory::handle_cleanup) == SIG_ERR)
    DLOG_S(INFO) << "Registering SIGABRT failed";
if (signal(SIGTERM, TemporaryDirectory::handle_cleanup) == SIG_ERR)
    DLOG_S(INFO) << "Registering SIGTERM failed";
if (signal(SIGINT, TemporaryDirectory::handle_cleanup) == SIG_ERR)
    DLOG_S(INFO) << "Registering SIGINT failed";
if (signal(SIGALRM, TemporaryDirectory::handle_cleanup) == SIG_ERR)
    DLOG_S(INFO) << "Registering SIGALRM failed";
```

And this is my handler method (which is static):

```
void test_utils::TemporaryDirectory::handle_cleanup(int signo) {
    DLOG_S(INFO) << "Received signal " << signo;
    if (signo == SIGABRT || signo == SIGTERM || signo == SIGINT || signo == SIGALRM) {
        DLOG_S(INFO) << "Cleaning up test files";
        TemporaryDirectory::test_files_root().cleanup();
    }
}
```

There are no registration failure messages in logs, but I am not seeing any signals being actually handled.

I have also tried changing the configuration by typing `handle all nostop` in GDB console, but even after doing that my application just dies.

Is there any way to clean up after clion's bundled GDB is stopped?

Comment: [Signal sent by the stopping button](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/203374490-Signal-sent-by-the-stopping-button)

Comment: @MarkPlotnick yes, I am aware it's GDB that is sending a signal. But what signal is it sending when you press that button in clion is a mystery to me. Also, I added clion in tags because there's a bundled GDB in it that might work differently from a standalone GDB...

Comment: Also—as you can see above—I have already tried handling `SIGTERM` to no avail.

Comment: As far as I can tell, if you're debugging (as opposed to running) the target, then CLion will send SIGINT to the target and then immediately send a `kill` command to gdb, which sends (via ptrace) the unignorable, uncatchable `SIGKILL` signal to the target, then CLion tells gdb to exit.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick alright, but is there any way to configure GDB not to send `SIGKILL`, but another (catchable) signal instead?

Comment: You can redefine gdb's `kill` command using `define kill`. You can make it do, say, `signal SIGTERM`, which will continue the target while sending it that signal. Maybe put `shell sleep 5` in there, too, so the target has a chance to run a bit before gdb processes the `-gdb-exit` command that CLion sends it.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick nope, didn't work `(gdb) define kill
Really redefine built-in command "kill"? (y or n) [answered Y; input not from terminal]
> sleep 5s; kill -s SIGTERM $@
> end` and the stop button still kills it without any warning

Comment: @MarkPlotnick alright, it worked! I was defining it wrong. `(gdb) define kill
Really redefine built-in command "kill"? (y or n) [answered Y; input not from terminal]
> signal SIGINT
> end` - thank you very much! Why don't you add it as an answer so I can accept it? (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, when you click on the `Stop` button while debugging a program, CLion will:

- if the target isn't already stopped, send a `SIGINT` signal to the target process, then read a response, if any, from gdb, about the target having received the signal
- send a `kill` command to gdb, which will result in gdb killing the target with an uncatchable, unignorable `SIGKILL` signal
- send a `-gdb-exit` command to gdb, which will cause gdb to exit

If SIGINT is sent, and if you have a SIGINT handler in your program and you've configured gdb to pass signals to the target with e.g. `handle SIGINT pass nostop noprint`, the target will run its SIGINT handler but will be killed a fraction of a second later by the `kill` command.

If you want to give your program a chance to clean up by invoking a signal handler, you can redefine gdb's `kill` command to send a signal of your choice, using the `signal` command:

```
define kill
  signal SIGTERM
  shell sleep 5
end
```

(OP has said that things worked as desired without needing the `shell sleep 5`.)

Answer (score 0):

To deal with a signal in gdb use `handle signal keywords...` in your debugging session. More details: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Signals.html

Btw; it's not gdb sending you signals, it's the kernel.

Comment: The point is, I don't know which signal GDB is sending upon stopping. I have tried `handle all nostop` command, which in my understanding should let me handle the signal from my application but it does not work.

Comment: Plus, I'm not even sure if GDB is sending any signals at all. Seems like it runs the app in a sandbox environment and kills it without any warnings...